# Lobstr Wallet Passcodes and Secret Codes

Tags: wallets

Can anyone direct me to a link or explain how to use passcodes or the secret code to reset lobster without losing the assets or open orders. My settings are corrupted and as I have these codes I wondered if they would help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All assets and orders are stored on the ledger. If you access the same account from a different UI / device everything will be there.
As you stated you have the recovery-phrase and the secret you can delete the account and start over with those.
If you have a spare device I would suggest you try to load the account onto that device just to verify it works for your before deleting data from your actual phone.